# Entity Framework dbcontext crashing during foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have an asp.net core mvc project.  I'm trying to get over 300+ records from a table(s) using entity framework.  Here are the models I have:

```
  public partial class Movies
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual MovieInfoes MovieInfoes { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MovieInfoes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Actors { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public virtual Movies IdNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

In the controller section, I have an action that is suppose to list the title, actors, and director data.

```
 public IActionResult ListAllMovies()
    {
        var movies = context.Movies.Include("MovieInfoes").ToList();
        foreach (var movie in movies)
        {
            string x = movie.MovieInfoes.Actors;
        }
        return View(movies);
    }
```

For some reason, it is crashing after it iterates 19 records (I'm trying to iterate thru 300+ records).  I get an error saying "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Note: I've tried with lazy loading and eager loading, and both ways result in same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely attempting to access `movie.MovieInfoes.Actors` with an instance of `movie` that has a `null` `MovieInfoes` reference.

**Try accessing `Actors` with a [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) by changing `string x = movie.MovieInfoes.Actors;` to `string x = movie?.MovieInfoes?.Actors;`**

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.  I hate when I miss dumb things like this.